# Getting the whole DNS record

Tags: terminal, dns, internet

I have a domain that has a DNS record with `CNAME` and `ALIAS` entries, but how do I check them in the terminal?

I tried `nslookup -type=any <domain.name>` and `dig <domain.name> any` and variants there of, but it seems like I don't get the whole record.

What knowledge gap do I have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `host -a example.com` to see a list of all DNS records of a domain.